# Spring Security Oauth2 Authorizarion Popup

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

How could it be changed Sparklr/Tonr example (`https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth`) of Spring Security Oauth2 plugin to open a popup asking user for permission instead of redirect him to another page?

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. You only need a short JS like this

```
window.open("http://localhost:8080/sparklr2/oauth/authorize?type=code&client_id=.....");
```

And depent on result, you should notify the parent window to do something. Eg: refresh like this

```
window.opener.location.reload(false);
```

This should work for both `implicit` and `authorization_code` grant.